# How make vim/neovim output window to show carriage return (\r) correctly

Tags: neovim

I am running an external command (`ninja build`) that uses carriage return `\r` to overwrite the last printed line.

- From the terminal:

```
$ ninja -C build
[2/2] Linking CXX executable a.out
```

- From vim:

```
:!ninja -C build
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.out.dir/main.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX executable a.out

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Version info:

```
nvim --version
NVIM v0.5.1
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/gcc-11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_TS_HAS_SET_MATCH_LIMIT -O2 -g -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/config -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/src -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/src/nvim/auto -I/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/include
Compiled by runner@fv-az87-829

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "
/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure I understand what the question is here. Do you want the "in-(neo)vim" output to only be the one line? That seems like it may be better directed at the developers. (P.S. in regular vim `:!printf 'hello\rgoodbye'` works for me like you suggest, so it could be a neovim issue. They generally recommend using `:terminal` over `:!`.)